# How conv2D function change the input layer

Tags: tensorflow, size, tensor, resnet

In my ResNet32 network coded using Tensorflow, the input size is 32 x 32 x 3 and the output of the 
layer is 32 x 32 x 32. Why 32 channel is used ?

```
tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(
    inputs,
    **num_outputs**,  /// how to determine the number of channel to be used in my layer?
    kernel_size,
    stride=1,
    padding='SAME',
    data_format=None,
    rate=1,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    normalizer_fn=None,
    normalizer_params=None,
    weights_initializer=initializers.xavier_initializer(),
    weights_regularizer=None,
    biases_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    biases_regularizer=None,
    reuse=None,
    variables_collections=None,
    outputs_collections=None,
    trainable=True,
    scope=None
)
```

Thank's in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The `3` in input is the number to represent that the input image is RGB (color image), also known as color channels, and if it were a black and white image then it would have been `1` (monochrome image).

The `32` in output of this represents the number of neurons\number of features\number of channels you are using, so basically you are representing the image in 3 colors with 32 channels. 
This helps in learning more complex and different set of features of the image. For example, it can make the network learn better edges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in this way the intermediate representation ( the outputs of the layers) is by far bigger then the input image, what i want to do is to make it smaller, how can I change this parameter which define the number of channel used , and does this affect the accuracy of my network, thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to compress images, you need to use `TransposedConvolution`, defined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose).

Comment: Thanks Rishabh, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning `stride=2` you can reduce the spatial size of input tensor so that the height and width of output tensor becomes half of that input tensor. That means, if your input tensor shape is `(batch, 32, 32, 3)` (3 is for RGB channel) to a Convolution layer having 32 kernels/filters with `stride=2` then the shape of output tensor will be `(batch, 16, 16, 32)`. Alternatively, Pooling is also widely used to reduce the output tensor size.

The ability of learning hierarchical representation by stacking conv layer is considered as the key to success of CNN. In CNN, as we go deeper the spatial size of the tensor reduces whereas the number of channel increases that helps to handle the variations in appearance of complex target object . This reduction of spatial size drastically decreases the required number of arithmetic operations and computation time with the motive of extracting prominent features contributing towards final output/decision. However, finding this optimal number of filter/kernel/output channel is time consuming and, therefore, people follow the proven earlier architectures e.g. VGG.